# How to combine two XML result elements in one column with jqGrid xmlmap?

Tags: jquery, xml, jqgrid, xmlmapper

I have a table, rendered with jqGrid where I want to combine two different XML elements in one column - for example I want to combine the elements, denoting Contact's first and last name in one column called "userName". There should also be a delimiter between the two values in the column. The format should be:
LastName, FirstName

If I try something like the selectors below, I get the first and last name, but the first name is displayed first, while I would like the last name to be displayed first, and there is no delimiter between the names - I don't know how to put the delimiter (", ") between the names:

```
colModel :[
    { name: "userName", index: "userName", xmlmap:'SearchResponse>Object[type="Contact"]>Attribute[name="last-name"],SearchResponse>Object[type="Contact"]>Attribute[name="first-name"]'}
]
```

I tried also some examples with using a fuction inside the xmlmap, but I ended up with [object, Object], [object, Object] inside that column instead of the real values.

Comment: `xmlmap: function (obj) { $(obj).find(">Contact").attr("last-name") + ", " + $(obj).find(">Contact").attr("first-name")` }?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, and thank you for the help. The example given was leading to the same results as mine - [object, Object], [object, Object] inside that column instead of the real values. Actually the issue was that you should have .text() after each of the selectors to get the actual content of the tag like this:

function (obj) { $(obj).find(">Contact").attr("last-name").text() + ", " + $(obj).find(">Contact").attr("first-name").text() }